# How to pass a JavaScript array to an XPages Java Controller

Tags: java, xpages

I'm working with jQuery DataTables.  I have it listing out a view and have checkboxes to select multiple documents.  I'm able to get the selected keys into session scope via this client side JavaScript code :

```
<xp:this.script><![CDATA[// Build array of selected rows
var myTableApi = x$("inventoryTable").DataTable();
var count = myTableApi.rows( { selected: true } ).count();
var dataArr = [];
var rowData = myTableApi.rows( { selected: true } ).data();
    $.each($(rowData),function(key,value){
        dataArr.push(value[3]);
    });

// Push that to the requestScope
setScopeValue("session", "rowCount", count);
setScopeValue("session", "rowIds", dataArr);]]></xp:this.script>
```

Once the id's are in Scope I change pages and then I want to load them into my Java pageController.

I can easily use a variable resolver to get ahold of "rowIds".  But I'm not sure how to get it into Java so I could work with it.  Ideally I'd like it to be List or Set or something similar.

In Java, how can I convert this JavaScript Array to a Collection based object?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that to pull the whole thing off I'm using some code pieces from this post : http://oliverbusse.notesx.net/hp.nsf/blogpost.xsp?documentId=BB6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few tricks to do here.

First, since the particular implementation of your `setScopeValue` function converts all values to a string before sending them to the server, it's important to do `setScopeValue("session", "rowIds", XSP.toJson(dataArr))`. That way, the value stored on the server will be `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` instead of `foobarbaz`.

Secondly, the best way to get to the session-scoped value in Java would be via `ExtLibUtil.getSessionScope().get("rowIds")`.

That value will be a string, though, and not an array type, so it'll have to be parsed from JSON. Using the IBM Commons JSON capabilities, that can be done with:

```
List<?> rowIds = (List<?>)JsonParser.fromJson(JsonJavaFactory.instance, ExtLibUtil.getSessionScope().get("rowIds"))
for(Object rowIdObj : rowIds) {
    String rowId = StringUtil.toString(rowIdObj);
    // do stuff with each ID here
}
```

You can also potentially case it directly to a `List<String>`, since Java's generics are really just hints for compiler-generated code, and not really enforced in the objects themselves, but there you run the risk of a `ClassCastException` if the incoming `List` contains any non-string types.